# How to make try function in PYTHON execute only once while except executes many times?

Tags: python, excel

How can I make my script print "number" only once if the "try" goes right and doesn't show errors?

When it goes wrong, I want it to keep trying and printing ("Error. Attempt: " + str(x)). But if it goes right I want it to print (number) only once.

This script was made in order to track when a certain excel spreadsheet is created in the folder. When it is in the folder, I want the script to print (number).

The issue is when the excel is already in the folder, the script keeps printing (number) 16 times, until num_retries is done.

```
num_retries = 16
interval = 2

for x in range(1, num_retries): 
    try:
        result = open("I:/workbook.xls")
        import xlrd
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("I:/workbook.xls")
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("sheet1")
        number = worksheet.cell(3, 13).value
        print(number)

    except:
        sleep(interval)
        print("Error. Attempt: " + str(x))
        pass
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `break` after `print(number)`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked

Comment: Using a plain `except:` statement is bad practice. Also, imports should go at the top of the file, and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `break` after your `print(number)` so when it gets the right number if jumps out of the loop. Your code would be like this:

```
for x in range(1, num_retries): 
    try:
        result = open("I:/workbook.xls")
        import xlrd
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("I:/workbook.xls")
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("sheet1")
        number = worksheet.cell(3, 13).value
        print(number)
        break

    except:
        sleep(interval)
        print("Error. Attempt: " + str(x))
        pass
```